# add an empty line between 2 spans

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to add an empty line between two text spans

```
    <span> The models have random values that I dont understand and it is not sufficenit but whatever </span>
    {'\n'}
    <span>Lots of text here </span>
```

The  {'\n'} does not seem to work. What else can I try?

Comment: You can also use `div` and provide CSS, like margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `<br/>` tag for this purpose

```
    <span> The models have random values that I dont understand and it is not 
       sufficenit but whatever </span>
    <br />
    <span>Lots of text here </span>
```

Answer (score 0):

As ali said you can use `<br>`

Or instead you can put them into `<p>` tag because they are text ...  span is not usually used on Lots of text

Code should be like this

```
<p> The models have random values that I dont understand and it is not sufficenit but whatever </p>
    
<p>Lots of text here </p>
```